# How to match a file path with a file search pattern (i.e. *.jpg)?

Tags: c#

I know how to get all files that match the search pattern in a folder like this:

```
DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

FileInfo[] fileInfos = folderInfo.GetFiles(searchPattern);
```

But my problem is, if I already know the file path, how can I match it with the search pattern? For compatibility, the search pattern has to be the same format like *.jpg or something.

Comment: Can you please add more information to your question. From what you wrote, it is not clear if you already have a file for example c:\folder\f.jpg and you want to figure out if there are more similar files in the same folder.

Comment: Could you rephrase your qs, i am not getting you.

Comment: `*.*` will match anything you throw at it, but this isn't what you really meant, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question as meaning you already have a string for the file path and just want to check whether it matches a certain pattern.  For this you first need to consider whether pattern patching is really what you need, it may be preferable to just use the extension directly for example.

Assuming that is not an option, you're probably going to want to use regular expressions.  You will need to convert the string with wild-cards to a regular expression.  Unfortunately I'm not aware of any built in ways of doing this, but it should be possible to do by simply escaping any characters which would have meaning in a regex and replacing the wild cards with appropriate regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you already have the full file path and you isolate the extension only, using Path.GetExtension or similar, then you just add a * before you are are set, right?

Answer (score 0):

If u already know the path, Don't use search pattern.
Try

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FilePath);
```

Comment: Did you even tried to get OPs qs right? Perhaps he is not looking for this solution.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Directory.GetFiles like "Directory.GetFiles("d:/xxx/*.jpg")" to get string array of all match files, and then to open or handle the single file.

Comment: This does not seem to work. Did you mean `Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\xxx", "*.jpg")`?